# XSS in my Web App?

Tags: web-application, xss, appsec

I have developed web app, and my customer is saying this piece of code is vulnerable:

```
<a href="#" onclick="count.it('count', 9); console.log(1);">Click
```

`"9"` is injection point

however its in `"template"` page and `count.it` is not defined, so not executing `console.log(1)`, is he right and this is security flaw made by me? I do not want to leave my customers vulnerable.

I tried multiple ways to execute XSS however I did not come up with any solution to fire up `console.log(1)`

`<>"'` characters are sanitized

Comment: Honestly, I don't understand your question. You know you have an XSS injection point and the only thing stopping it is a bug. Why don't you fix the bug and the XSS? If you don't want to leave your customers vulnerable then fix the issues. All it takes is someone fixing the bug and then you are vulnerable (assuming you aren't already)

Answer (score 1):

I believe he is right.  It sounds like the parameter that provides the '9' is under control of the user / provided by the query string in the URL that links to this page, right?

Since the parameter is already inside some JavaScript, the attacker would not need to inject angle brackets or quotes to inject JavaScript code and cause a Cross-site Scripting (XSS).

Your goal as you simulate the attack is not to fire the `console.log(1)` statement you provided in the code but to execute some code that is provided in place of the value '9'.  To see it at work, instead of the '9' put some string like:

```
9); alert(505
```

or

```
9); console.log(1)
```

(without seeing the entire page as it is rendered, it is difficult to predict exactly what XSS might work.  If you'd like further help, please paste the source code of the loaded page)

**You could also just skip ahead to fixing the issue:**

What you would need to do to make the finding go away is validate the parameter before it is used and stop the user or stop the page load if the value contains anything besides  digits.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however alert, or console.log wont be executed cause count.it is not defined (console error) so as far as I know there is no possible way to execute malicious JS injected by attacker.


where 9 value is, from there entire JS can be manipulated by attacker. If you try my example and click on it you will see what I mean - by looking in browser console.

Comment: if it is a template file you are working on, won't it be included in many pages, some with the function count_it() defined?

Comment: yes, you are right, the params are passed to the template file, and then loaded on the page, but how would attacker be able to edit the params, he would have to intercept the template request and then insert the xss payload in param, then click on it rendered on the page. Which would be self-xss. I was trying to figure out the reflected xss "way" right on the template page where count.it is not defined.

Comment: I would say that the attacker doesn't care if the vulnerable URL they find results in a full page being successfully loaded or some part thereof.  Again without seeing the actual page, I can only speculate but the attacker wouldn't try to intercept the template request, they would just find the URL with the vulnerable parameter and use that.  I grant you that this requires the extra step of making the victim click the the link or visiting a web page with the link... but this scenario is what your customer's finding is warning about.